# Sharepoint Server 2010 unable to map network drive

Tags: networking, dictionary, sharepoint-2010, drive

We're having a Sharepoint Server 2010 where we used to copy the files into the server by connecting to a mapped network drive. Since few days we're unable to map the network drive. We're able to make a remote connection to the server and also able to ping and access the shared file from the server. It is an annoying situation when it is accessed through remote and network and not able to access through map network drive. Can anyone help what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

What is the exact problem with the mapping?

Didn't you find the server or does it report any error message when you try to map the drive?

First thing I would check is the mapping table.

Open a command line (cmd.exe) with admin rights and type:

```
net use
```

That should give you a list of mapped drives.
If your server is listed, delete this mapping

```
net use /d \\your_server\share
```

Now or if your share has not been listed, try to map it here

```
net use drive: \\your_server\share
```

If it works all is fine, if not, give us the error message.
Often mapping problems are caused by (wins) browsing problems. Try to use

```
net use drive: \\your_server_ip\share
```

instead of

```
net use drive: \\your_server_name\share
```

too.

If this does not work, check your firewall settings and make sure file and printer sharing is allowed and your desired Folder/drive is shared correctly.

Comment: As you said the server name I'm trying to map is present in the list when i use the command net use. I'd deleted this mapping by using the command net use /d \\server_name. But I could not able to map it again. The error I'm getting after passing the credentials 4 to 5 times is windows cannot access \\server_name\share with error code 0x80070035 The network path was not found. I'd even tried to use net use drive: \\server_name\share, but I'm getting a message The network name cannot be found

Comment: Did you try to use the ip instead of the name?  This is a typical error when something is wrong with the name resolution.

Comment: I'm able to access the another server through map drive. I think there would be some problem with the network access authorizations. But, my doubt is if it is accessible through network and remote why can't it be done through mapping?

Comment: I'd tried with ip and with server name. But no use.

Comment: Then you may check the firewall settings of the server. It should allow File and Printer Sharing inside the type of network you use.

Comment: File and printer sharing is enabled in the firewall settings. I'd also tried enabling windows firewall remote management, net logon service and remote administration. But, no use